# How do I escape JSON strings in python mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-python, mysql-connector

To clarify I am using Python 3.10.9 along with mysql.connector

I am trying to insert a JSON string into my DB but I get a syntax error

```
func_locals -> {'protocol_id': '1', 
                'sock_object': '<create_socket.CreateSocket object at 0x7f8f3e1ae0>',
                'sock': "<socket.socket fd=16, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET,
                 type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>"}


Error from program_logging_table => 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
to use near '0.0.0.0', 0)>"}', 
'<socket.socket fd=16, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=S...' at line 1
```

Per my understand the problem is the single quotes being used inside the JSON `'`

Should I be using something along the lines of `db_connection._cmysql.escape_string()`

I get an error in the editor `Access to a protected member _cmysql of a class`

EDIT:
I am explicitly converting a dict into JSON

```
        locals_json = json.dumps(func_locals)
        print(f'locals_json -> {locals_json}')
```

And the mysql table is expecting JSON

```
CREATE TABLE program_logging_table(
...
program_logging_parameters JSON,
```

```
func_locals -> {'protocol_id': '1', 'sock_object':
 '<create_socket.CreateSocket object at 0x7fb51edc00>', 'sock':
 "<socket.socket fd=16, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET,
 type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>"}


locals_json -> {"protocol_id": "1", "sock_object":
 "<create_socket.CreateSocket object at 0x7fb51edc00>", "sock":
 "<socket.socket fd=16, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET,
 type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 0)>"}
```

EDIT2:
I'm adding the SQL statement for further clarity:

```
                f"INSERT INTO program_logging_table ("
                f"program_logging_function_name, "
                f"program_logging_function_description, "
                f"program_logging_parameters, "
                f"program_logging_return_value, "
                f"program_logging_initial_timestamp, "
                f"program_logging_final_timestamp)"
                f"VALUES( "
                f"'{self.function_name}', "
                f"'{self.function_description}', "
                f"'{self.variables_dictionary}', "
                f"'{self.return_value}', "
                f"'{self.initial_timestamp}', "
                f"'{self.final_timestamp}');"
```

Where variables dictionary would the `locals_json` from my previous edit

Comment: JSON uses `""` and never single quotes.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: That is the purpose of my question. I have single quotes being used inside the JSON string that need to be escape, how do I achieve that?

Comment: For start, are you sure that you deal with `str`  (clearly not JSON string) and not `dict`?

Comment: @buran I updated the OP to mention that I am converting a dict into json, and the database is expecting JSON type

Comment: @RiggsFolly JsonLint.com is not giving me any issues with the JSON string either, maybe I am misunderstanding the error I am getting but I thought it was due to the use of single quotes

Comment: You shouldn't be constructing the INSERT SQL statement yourself. Use parametrized statement and `cursor.execute()`